# How do I down/upgrade PHP on XAMPP to 5.3.0/5.3.2?

Tags: upgrade, php, xampp

I've been reading [this](http://lifehacker.com/354005/run-your-personal-wikipedia-from-a-usb-stick) tutorial but when i go to localhost/wiki it says:
PHP 5.3.1 is not compatible with MediaWiki due to a bug involving reference parameters to __call. Upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher, or downgrade to PHP 5.3.0 to fix this. ABORTING
It's XAMPP lite

How can i upgrade or downgrade it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downgrade to [XAMPP 1.7.2](http://filepig.org/download/xampp_lite/) which has PHP 5.3.2; until PHP 5.3.2 becomes available.